# Spring MVC custom validation issue with interface

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

I'm trying to do my own validation for category product. It is a task from 
**Spring MVC: Beginner's Guide** book.
I have write a interface where i need to have validation for category where user cannot write diffrent category then is in set.

```
@Target({METHOD, FIELD, ANNOTATION_TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = CategoryValidator.class)
@Documented
public @interface ICategory {

        List<String> allowedCategories;
        String message() default "{com.packt.webstore.validator.category.message}";
        Class<?>[] groups() default {};
        public abstract Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};

    }
```

In the task i should maintain a `List<String> allowedCategory`. But there i have a warning:

> "The blank final field allowedCategories may not have been
>   initialized"

What am I doing wrong?  Can't I use a field in interface? What should I do instead?

And below I show you mine implementation class of that interface:

```
@Component
public class CategoryValidator implements ConstraintValidator<IProductId, String>{ 

    private List<String> allowedCategories;
    public CategoryValidator() {
        allowedCategories = getAllCategories(productService.getAllProducts());
    }

    private List<String> getAllCategories(List<Product> products) {
        List<String> categories = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Product product :  products) {
            categories.add(product.getCategory());
        }
        return categories;
    }

    @Autowired
    private IProductService productService;

    public void initialize(IProductId constraintAnnotation) {

    }

    public boolean isValid(String value, ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
        for (String category :  allowedCategories) {
            if(category.equals(value)) {
                return true;
            }           
        }
        return false;
    }

}
```

Comment: I'm not 100% sure what you are trying to do. But how about if you change `List<String> allowedCategories` for `List<String> getAllowedCategories()` and let the implementing class define which categories are allowed. This sounds more coherent to me.

Comment: When i change for `List<String> getAllowedCategories();` I can't compile because of that warning: _- Invalid type List<String> for the annotation attribute ICategory.allowedCategories; 
  only primitive type, String, Class, annotation, enumeration are permitted or 1-dimensional 
  arrays thereof_

Comment: Then define array of categories `String[] getAllowedCategories()`

Comment: now i have an error Instantiation of bean failed; _nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [com.packt.webstore.validator.CategoryValidator]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException_